# flutter: migrating to androidx

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-services, androidx

When using android studio, creating a new project and adding the following entries to:
`android/build.gradle` (dependencies):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

and `android/app/build.gradle` (at the bottom)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the gradle build fails with the following error:

```
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This error goes away when I stop to apply the google-services plugin, which I need for google services.
Flutter is upgraded to the latest version.

Complete build files:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }

    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }

    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }

    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28

        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }

        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "de.sveri.shopli_new"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }

    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Do you have other details about the error? Did you add the google-services.json file?

Comment: The hint for the json file was the solution. I copied it from another project and forgot to adapt the package name.

Comment: I've just added the same hint as answer. It can be useful for other users. There is no obligation to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the [setup of the google play services plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file) you have to

- add the `google-services.json` file.

> This file is generally placed in the `app/ directory` (at the root of the Android Studio app module). As of version 2.2.0 the plugin supports build type and product flavor specific JSON files. All of the following directory structures are valid:

```
// dogfood and release are build types.
app/
    google-services.json
    src/dogfood/google-services.json
    src/release/google-services.json
```